# How to execute node.js from php on centos os on nginx server?

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, centos, digital-ocean

Hi I want to execute my notification.js which includes nodes libraries, from php . I've done it on my local pc which have ubuntu os using below code but same is not working on centos. Anyone knows how to do it??

```
<?php exec('/usr/bin/node '.JAVASCRIPT_PATH.'Server.js');?>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? What is the output of the exec call? Does the /usr/bin/node exists? Do you have access to it?

Comment: On cent os node exits in /usr/bin/node I've this path in my code which is on cents os but it's not worrking.

Comment: We are not mind readers - we need some kind of error output. Try running this command in CLI, outside PHP and see what happens.

Comment: If I run this command in CLI the connection succeeds and it doesn't shows any error.

Comment: Then refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for how to get error output here.

Comment: I am getting empty array as output and following error in firebug.

    ReferenceError: io is not defined
 var socket = io.connect('http://silkeletz.com:8000');

Comment: Then your problem has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: That's why I also specified the os and server in my question.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with any of them either! You have an error in your node.js script which is clearly stated by the error output (it seems you have not installed dependencies). Please, put some effort in what you are doing before asking us to do everything for you.

Comment: I've installed the dependencies and it's working if I execute the file from CLI. And I have also included the node modules directory which is required by the script file which includes this modules.

Comment: Is JAVASCRIPT_PATH your current working directory in PHP?

Comment: It's a constant for the javascript path which includes all js files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by keeping node_modules directory any my script file which includes the node library in root directory of my project.